# Angular JS Application is not Working wiht WCF Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Service into Angular Js Application . I have one Boolean function inside the wcf service to accept the username and password. I am trying to create user login system by using Angular Js Application. If user enter correct username and password, I want redirect user into welcome page but when I enter the correct username and password its does not working according my expectation. There are no errors showing in Google Chrome console windows.

Here is Interface .

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "/AuthenticateUser")]
        bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin);
```

Here is Implementation ..

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            // ConfigurationManager class is in System.Configuration namespace
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            // SqlConnection is in System.Data.SqlClient namespace
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Formsauthentication is in system.web.security
                string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");

                //sqlparameter is in System.Data namespace
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
                SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (RetryAttempts > 0)
                    {
                        int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);
                        //lblMessage.Text = "Invalid user name and/or password. " +
                        //    AttemptsLeft.ToString() + "attempt(s) left";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is Script code .

```
///// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";


        }


        $scope.login = function () {
            var User = {
                Username: $scope.Username,
                Password: $scope.Password,


            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {
                var promisePost = myService.post(User);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.Id = pl.data.Id;
                    window.location.href = "/Login/WelcomePage";

                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    $scope.msg = "Password Incorrect !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            } 

        };



    }]);

app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    //Create new record  

    this.AuthenticateUser = function () {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser");
    }


})
```

Here is the HTML code..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Username</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="username" data-ng-model="Username" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Password</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" required data-ng-model="Password" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" data-ng-click="login()" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
```

Here is the screen shot when I run the application.[image: Click here to see the result]

Any Help or suggestion will he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
var promisePost = myService.post(User);
```

indicates that myService has a post method. Whereas it doesn't.

```
app.service("myService", function ($http) {
//Create new record  

    this.AuthenticateUser = function () {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser");
    }
})
```

try

```
var promisePost = myService.AuthenticateUser(User);
```

and modify

```
//add user to function param, and pass in post
this.AuthenticateUser = function (user) {
    return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser", JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

I'd further recommend to implement an interceptor, and use $q to resolve promises. [this is a great tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

Comment: Is that an API error ? any more details of the error message you could post ? Also, can debug the API/WCF to see if you are receiving a proper User object.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
LoginScript.js:54 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: I open google chrome console windows I got this errors

Comment: I sounds like somewhere you missed closing a bracket/curly bracket or possibly semi cologne. If you click on the error in chrome, it should take you to line 54 of LoginScript.js. Make sure all you statements in your js files are properly closed.

Comment: still same response its unable to  cheek the username and password ,not redirecting user to welcome page or displaying username or password incorrect